# Android Location from Startup

Tags: android, android-location

i am currently developing an app that requires location from the start. I have a method that checks if location updates are up, but even when GPS is turned up I cant ensure a Location Update when the app starts. How can I ensure a fresh location update when my app starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i am currently developing an app that requires location from the start.

That is a design flaw in your app. Please redesign your app to take into account that:

- the user may have GPS disabled, or
- the user may not have used GPS recently, so it will take some time to acquire a fix, or
- the user may not be in a location where GPS signals are available (e.g., inside a large building)

> How can I ensure a fresh location update when my app starts?

You can't.

Comment: Hmm ok, so the best that  i can do is a request last location on both providers (GPS and WIFI) and use it while i dont receive a fresh one is it?

Comment: @user1437481: Yes. You might also considering requesting location updates for both providers, as there is no guarantee that `getLastKnownLocation()` will work for any provider, and the network provider has a chance to give you a response faster.